# delegate.replace() is not working on Array List Grails 2.3.8

Tags: html, arrays, grails, tags

Here's my code in order to replace HTML tags:

```
  def str
  String.metaClass.removeHtml {
      def removeThisHtml = [
         [htmlCode: "&#96;",  value: "`"], 
         [htmlCode: "&#64;",  value: "@"], 
         [htmlCode: "&amp;",  value: "&"],
         [htmlCode: "&#92;",  value: "\\"],
         [htmlCode: "&quot;", value: '"'], 
         [htmlCode: "&#39;",  value: "'"], 
         [htmlCode: "&lt;",   value: "<"],
         [htmlCode: "&gt;",   value: ">"]
      ]

      removeThisHtml.each { element ->
         str = delegate.replace(element.htmlCode, element.value)
      } 
      return str
  }
```

And here is the code form my controller:

```
def getProjectLists() {
  def currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
  def kups = ([['name':'<b>Sample 1</b>'.removeHtml()],['name':'<b>Sample 2</b>']])
  render kups as JSON  
}
```

My expected output is:

< b >Sample1<  / b> **Sample2**

But the output is:

**Sample1** **Sample2**

Comment: in this case the normal string replace function should work https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Thanks Lars, but i need this replace function on my back end part. Grails 2.3.8

Comment: oh sorry i did not see the "grails" tag... you might want to include the used technologie in the question

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the tip .

Comment: Are you looking for this: `String.metaClass.removeHtml {
    return org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(delegate)
}`?

Comment: @SaschaFrinken Based on his code, it actually looks like he's trying to decode Html escape sequences into the text equivalent.  But based on his output, you're right, he wants to escapeHtml it.

Comment: @Kim Remonte Seems like my suggestion was the correct answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149915/methods-implementation-for-future-grails-project). It would be nice if you either ask me to write this as an answer or answer it by your self.  Doing it this way, other SO users can benefit from it.

Comment: @SaschaFrinken, hi sir i'm sorry. Yes your suggestion solved my problem. Please write this as answer and again thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you really want is to escape HTML - display HTML tags and entities, so the function's name `removeHtml` is a bit misleading, `escapeHtml` would fit it better.

Generally I recommend not to do things like this by your self as others have already done that and most likely do it better.

For example **Apache Commons** has an `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml` method.

```
String.metaClass.removeHtml { 
    return org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(delegate) 
}
```