# Methods implementation for future grails project

Tags: function, class, grails, methods

i just want to ask for any of your ideas on what method to be created, i mean a useful method that can be implement to any grails project. Thanks!

Here is my example method

```
String.metaClass.htmlEscape {
    return org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(delegate)
}
```

and here's how you call it in the controller

```
def kups = ([['name':'<marquee direction="up">"Sample 1"</marquee>'.htmlEscape()],['name':'<b>Sample 2</b>'.htmlEscape()]])
render kups as JSON
```

and the output is

```
<marquee direction="up">"Sample 1"</marquee> <b>Sample 2</b>
```

So guys please me for any method ideas Thanks :)

Comment: but to render in the view to the user ?

Comment: I actually use ajax for that sir